# API-level Unicode GUI Native apps in C++ for Windows/Linux/Mac

Tags: c++, user-interface, utf-8, cross-platform, native

## API-level Unicode GUI Native apps in C++ for Windows / Linux / Mac OS X.

I am looking for writing a simple **Unicode**, **GUI**, **Native**, application, that can be run without need any non-standard library, written in C++ compiled with GNU-GCC (g++).

### NOT

I don't mean one-code-source run-anywhere, but 3 (Win/Linux/Mac) code source! run-without-library (native application).

- Native application

  Application can run without need any non-standard library, only the operating system C++ runtime (like MSVCRT on Windows).
- Unicode application

  Right-to-left Window Layout (to support Right to left reading languages), with two buttons [Message] to show UTF-8 strings ("اهلا بالعالم") in a message-box, and [Exit] to... I think exit! :p

---

### The solution for Windows (Windows 7)

- Compiler: MinGW g++ 4.5.0
- Command line: `g++ -Wl,--enable-auto-import -O2 -fno-strict-aliasing -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -D_UNICODE -DUNICODE -mwindows -Wall test.cpp -o test.exe`

```
#include (windows.h)
#include (tchar.h)
#include (string)

typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> ustring;

LONG StandardExtendedStyle;

TCHAR buffer_1[1024];
TCHAR buffer_2[1024];

static HWND button_1;
static HWND button_2;

inline int ErrMsg(const ustring& s)
{
 return MessageBox(0,s.c_str(),_T("ERROR"),MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd,UINT uMsg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
{
switch (uMsg)
 {
 case WM_CREATE:

 button_1=CreateWindow(L"button",L"UTF-8 Message",WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,10,10,120,25,hwnd,(HMENU)1,NULL,NULL);
 button_2=CreateWindow(L"button",L"Exit",WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE,10,50,120,25,hwnd,(HMENU)2,NULL,NULL);

 break;
 
 case WM_COMMAND:
 
  switch(LOWORD(wParam))
  {

    case 1:

    _stprintf(buffer_1,L"اهلا بالعالم");
    _stprintf(buffer_2,L"Hello World in Arabic !");
    MessageBoxW(hwnd,buffer_1,buffer_2,MB_ICONINFORMATION|MB_OK|MB_RTLREADING|MB_RIGHT);

    break;

    case 2:

    PostQuitMessage(0);

    break;

  }break;
  
  case WM_CLOSE:

  DestroyWindow(hwnd);

  break;
  
  case WM_DESTROY:

  PostQuitMessage(0);

  break;
  
  default:
   return DefWindowProc(hwnd,uMsg,wParam,lParam);
 }
  return 0;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst,HINSTANCE,LPSTR pStr,int nCmd)
{

 ustring classname=_T("window");
 WNDCLASSEX window={0};
 window.cbSize        = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
 window.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc;
 window.hInstance     = hInst;
 window.hIcon         = (HICON)LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(100), IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, 0);
 window.hCursor       = reinterpret_cast<HCURSOR>(LoadImage(0,IDC_ARROW,IMAGE_CURSOR,0,0,LR_SHARED));
 window.hbrBackground = reinterpret_cast<HBRUSH>(COLOR_BTNFACE+1);
 window.lpszClassName = classname.c_str(); 

 if (!RegisterClassEx(&window))
 {
   ErrMsg(_T("Failed to register wnd class"));return -1;
 }

 int desktopwidth=GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
 int desktopheight=GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

 HWND hwnd=CreateWindowEx(0,classname.c_str(),_T("The solution for Windows"),WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,desktopwidth/4,desktopheight/4,270,150,0,0,
hInst,0);

 if (!hwnd)
 {
  ErrMsg(_T("Failed to create wnd"));
  return -1;
 }

 StandardExtendedStyle=GetWindowLong(hwnd,GWL_EXSTYLE);
 SetWindowLong(hwnd,GWL_EXSTYLE,StandardExtendedStyle|WS_EX_LAYOUTRTL);
 ShowWindow(hwnd,nCmd); 
 UpdateWindow(hwnd);
 MSG msg;
 while (GetMessage(&msg,0,0,0)>0)
 {
  TranslateMessage(&msg);
  DispatchMessage(&msg);
 }
 return static_cast<int>(msg.wParam);
}
```

NOTE: This application is attached only with MSVCRT.DLL, that mean is a native windows C++ application.

---

### The solution for Linux

Please HELP!

How to run the application on Linux without telling the user to install this and this.. a native Linux application!

- What is the file format must be? ELF, Bin...?
- X11 is the native Linux GUI library? or WxWidgets, QT, GTK+, gtkmm.. ???!!!
- Can be run on Gnome and KDE? or need a different code source?

Any one know the solution for Linux?

---

### The solution for Mac OS X

Please HELP!

I think the solution for Mac OS X is Cocoa in C++ with G++! but I'm not sure!

- Can G++ build a native Mac OS application with Cocoa?

Comment: I think you mean "API-level" app, could you edit your question to specify that? Also, exactly what do you mean by "complete"? The simplest Unicode API-level Windows app just calls `MessageBox` in `main`, nothing more...

Comment: Yes, i mean API-Level, whats is the equivalent on Linux ? POSIX and GTK ? and what about Mac ? Cocoa ?

Answer (score 6):

Or [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/). Not 'native' but neither is MFC, WPF, Silverlight ....

Comment: I prefer it to wx but I didn't want to start a war! wx has a slightly more flexible license if that matters to you.

Comment: +1 for Qt.  We are using it for a large Windows, Mac and Linux app and it's brilliant.

Comment: Qt is probably the worst you can get with respect to UI quality. It's bloated, slow (due to software rendering), doesn't use native controls (as of version 4), and sports an unusable keyboard interface. If that wasn't bad enough already, you never know, who owns Qt tomorrow. Trolltech? Nokia? Digia? The Qt Company? Someone else? wxWidgets, on the other hand, does use native controls, and produces overall better UI quality applications.

Answer (score 2):

X11 has **NO** native GUI library. Learn wxWidgets and use it on all three platforms. It will handle the interface to Win32 and Quartz for you.

Comment: wxWidgets not native too.. you need to add the wxWidgets dll to the EXE to be run, that mean not small in size ^_^

Comment: My time is usually worth *far* more than the customer's download bandwidth or hard drive space.

Comment: yes you are right, some kilobytes added to the application is not a problem, you think wxWidgets is best ? or gtkmm ? GTK+ ?

Comment: There is no complete native port of GTK+ for Quartz yet, so don't bother considering it at this time.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams for posterity, there certainly is now! maintained and made easily installable by the good folks at [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) and worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

Windows API:

```
#undef  UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#include    <windows.h>

int main()
{
    MessageBox(
        0,
        L"اهلا بالعالم",
        L"Hello World in Arabic !",
        MB_ICONINFORMATION | MB_SETFOREGROUND
        );
}
```

Building with MinGW g++ (producing `a.exe`):

> C:\test> g++ --version | find "++" g++
>   (TDM-2 mingw32) 4.4.1
>
> C:\test> g++ -O -pedantic -std=c++98
>   -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wno-long-long -mwindows x.cpp
>
> C:\test> _

Building with Visual C++ (producing `x.exe`):

> C:\test> (cl /nologo- 2>&1) | find "++"
>   Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++
>   Optimizing Compiler Version
>   16.00.30319.01 for 80x86
>
> C:\test> cl /nologo /EHsc /GR
>   /Zc:forScope,wchar_t /W4 x.cpp /link
>   user32.lib /subsystem:windows
>   /entry:mainCRTStartup
>   x.cpp
>
> C:\test> _

I think this is fairly "complete", but it's unclear what "complete" means.

Anyway, hth.

Comment: Thank you Steinbach, i added a window to your code its solved my problem about Windows, but what about Linux and Mac ?! ^_^